# How to change bar colors in a waterfall chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create my first waterfall chart, using ggplot2. I am new to ggplot2 and its (weird) syntax, so please be patient.

I found [this](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/) website, which I followed and everything worked perfectly. However, I hate the colors. How do I change the bars to different shades of red and green? (Secondary question - how do I get rid of the legend?)

I used this dataframe:

```
> wfDF
                 category   value sign id    end  start
1         Basic Materials  0.0024  pos  1 0.0024 0.0000
2          Communications  0.0492  pos  2 0.0516 0.0024
3      Consumer, Cyclical  0.0268  pos  3 0.0784 0.0516
4  Consumer, Non-cyclical  0.0245  pos  4 0.1029 0.0784
5             Diversified -0.0037  neg  5 0.0992 0.1029
6                  Energy -0.0040  neg  6 0.0952 0.0992
7               Financial  0.0445  pos  7 0.1397 0.0952
8              Industrial  0.0006  pos  8 0.1403 0.1397
9              Technology -0.0059  neg  9 0.1344 0.1403
10                  Total  0.1345  pos 10 0.0000 0.1344
```

With this code:

```
ggplot(wfDF, aes(category, fill = sign)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(x = category, xmin = id - 0.475, xmax = id + 0.475, ymin = end, ymax = start)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +     
  scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(wfDF$category), labels = gsub(" ", "\n", levels(wfDF$category)))
```

To create this plot:

[image]

Comment: There's got to be 10 answered questions on changing bar colors in ggplot2...

Comment: I found these, but from my limited experience, I could not get them to apply correctly. I found a way to change all the bars to the same color (not useful), I found a way using scale_color_manual (which did nothing), etc. So, I was hoping you could use the constructs of what I already have and let me know how, within this code, I could do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add scale_fill_manual to the end of your ggplot code, and then put in whatever colors your want.

```
ggplot(wfDF, aes(category, fill = sign)) + 
geom_rect(aes(x = category, xmin = id - 0.475, xmax = id + 0.475, ymin = end,   ymax = start)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +     
scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(wfDF$category), labels = gsub(" ", "\n",   levels(wfDF$category))) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue"))
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much. I was trying to use scale_color_manual, which did nothing. What is scale_color_manual supposed to be used for?

Comment: Ah - looks like color does the border, which seems to be a ggplot2 convention. Wonderful. Thank you very much for your help.